# openCV's EMD-L1 algorithm computes distances that are zeroes

Tags: c++, opencv

In the following code, I have two histograms, that for this simple example, I hard-coded in the source.  Each histogram have 128 bins, where the 64 firsts bins correspond to one histogram, and the 64 other correspond to another histogram.  However the resultant distance is `0`, even though there are clear differences in the latter 64 bins of the 128 bins of each vector.  I don't understand how it's possible why two different vectors have a null distance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/shape/emdL1.hpp>

using Vec128f = cv::Vec<float, 128>;

float sum_of_emd_dists(const Vec128f& a, const Vec128f& b)
{
    const cv::Mat a_color(cv::Size{64, 1}, CV_32FC1, (void*)(&a.val[0]));
    const cv::Mat a_label(cv::Size{64, 1}, CV_32FC1, (void*)(&a.val[64]));
    const cv::Mat b_color(cv::Size{64, 1}, CV_32FC1, (void*)(&b.val[0]));
    const cv::Mat b_label(cv::Size{64, 1}, CV_32FC1, (void*)(&b.val[64]));
    float dist = cv::EMDL1(a_color, b_color) + cv::EMDL1(a_label, b_label);
    return dist;
}



int main()
{
    Vec128f a = {64, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.265625, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.734375, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    Vec128f b = {64, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.109375, 0, 0, 0, 0.109375, 0, 0, 0.09375, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0625, 0, 0, 0.09375, 0, 0, 0, 0.046875, 0.046875, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.078125, 0.140625, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.09375, 0, 0, 0.0625, 0, 0, 0, 0.0625, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    std::cerr << "dist = " << sum_of_emd_dists(a, b) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
dist = 0
```

Thank you for any help explaining why theEMD-L1 distance is 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats because your matrix size is 1 row and 64 cols and you need single col martix.

Comment: Yes because *width* correspond to *cols* and nto *rows*, I forgot that `(width=a, height=b)` is `(rows=b,cols=a)`.